# Do subsets always form subbases?

Tags: general-topology

Lets say we have a family of subsets of $X$ such that the union of the subsets is equal to $X$. Will such a family of subsets necessarily be the subbasis for some topology $\tau$ on $X$? I cannot think of a counterexample.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: What is your definition of subbase?

Comment: A sub-base  for a topology on $X$ is defined to be a family $ F$ of subsets of  $X$ such that  $\{\cap G : G \in [F]^{<\omega}\}$  is a base for a topology on $X$, where  $[F]^{<\omega}$  is the set of all finite subsets of  $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Because if $ B$ is the the family of finite intersections from your original family then $\cup B =X$, and $B$ is closed under finite intersections,which are sufficient conditions for $B$ to be a base for a topology on $X$. Some people say "basis".Every topologist I met calls it a "base".

Comment: Subbase and base, yes, not -basis. And the union equals $X$ condition is not really necessary, if we include the empty intersection, which equals $X$, in the set of finite intersections. Then for *any* $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$, $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase for a topology, and the topology it generates is just the minimal one that contains $\mathcal{S}$. So even $\mathcal{S} = \emptyset$ then generates a topology, the indiscrete one.

Comment: The usual requirement for a base B for a topology T on X is that every member of T is a union of members of B, so the condition that the union equals X is necessary. However you can modify this if requirement if you like.As long as  you  define your terms..For example, I make a habit of saying "positive integer" and avoid "natural number " because half the people include 0 in the natural numbers, and half of them don't.